# Changing module based on condition

Tags: python, module

I just want to know is it possible to change the imported module based on conditional input?
This is the interface that I build and I planned from this interface it will change the imported configuration file to another configuration file when the configuration option button being click.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcXPm.png)

This is some part of the configuration file:

```
# Hardware config.

# Maximum velocity for each axis in millimeter per minute.
MAX_VELOCITY_MM_PER_MIN_X = 24000
MAX_VELOCITY_MM_PER_MIN_Y = 12000
MAX_VELOCITY_MM_PER_MIN_Z = 600
MAX_VELOCITY_MM_PER_MIN_E = 1500
MIN_VELOCITY_MM_PER_MIN = 1
# Average velocity for endstop calibration procedure
CALIBRATION_VELOCITY_MM_PER_MIN = 300

# Stepper motors steps per millimeter for each axis.
STEPPER_PULSES_PER_MM_X = 100
STEPPER_PULSES_PER_MM_Y = 100
STEPPER_PULSES_PER_MM_Z = 400
STEPPER_PULSES_PER_MM_E = 150

# Invert axises direction, by default(False) high level means increase of
# position. For inverted(True) axis, high level means decrease of position.
STEPPER_INVERTED_X = True
STEPPER_INVERTED_Y = False
STEPPER_INVERTED_Z = False
STEPPER_INVERTED_E = True
```

So the idea is, I want to have multiple configuration file where it have different value of the same variable. And i want to import the configuration file based on the configuration button.

is it possible to do that or is there any other way to do as such?

Comment: You can do this and I would recommend it with slight changes. A file does not necessarily need to be a module (.py) you could go with another typ, json is an option an natively supported by python. You could also have just a single file with keywords and multiple values (nested *dicts*) and filter them by a specific key to get the desired output.

Comment: Hi Thingamabobs, thank you so much for the answer. I have tried conditional import but the variable in the rest of the code (where the variable value in configuration.py file) become error. All the variable is not defined error. Why is it happened?